# Display ValueMember when selection is changed

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have searched all day for what I would think would be a simple concept, but that is what I get for thinking.

I have a DataGridView control with a ComboBox column that uses a DataTable as its DataSource as follows:

```
    With CType(dgvICS213.Columns(GridCol("CostBasis").Name), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
        .DataSource = Common.ExecuteQuery("SELECT ID, CostBasis FROM ICS213CostBasis", CommandType.Text)
        .DisplayMember = "CostBasis"
        .ValueMember = "ID"
    End With
```

The database table stores the value (ID) from the combo box.

I use the DefaultValuesNeeded event to set new values to the DisplayMember (CostBasis) value:

```
Dim dgv As DataGridView = sender
CType(e.Row.Cells(GridCol("CostBasis").Index), DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Value = CType(dgv.Columns(GridCol("CostBasis").Index), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).Items(0).Item(1)
```

I also use the DisplayMember value to fill existing rows from a database query (handling the DataError event)

So far, so good but when I select a an entry from the combox, the ValueMember is displayed in the combo instead of the DisplayMember. Can someone explain where I am going wrong.

Comment: this shouldn't be relevant but why do you have two different gv names here : `dgvICS213` and `dgv`

Comment: It is the same grid - I amended the post.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and solved it by changing the field in the database from `byte` to `int16`.